# Error getting audio input stream from input URL

Tags: java, javasound

I am trying to play a .WAV in Java using the code from the javasound.info:

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class LoopSound {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL(
            http://www.mediafire.com/listen/vgtpaigmj3un9ii/Untitled34.wav");
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        // getAudioInputStream() also accepts a File or InputStream
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.
            getAudioInputStream( url );
        clip.open(ais);
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // A GUI element to prevent the Clip's daemon Thread
                // from terminating at the end of the main()
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Close to exit!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input URL
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1153)
    at LoopSound.main(Wanderando.java:13)
```

I assume that the problem is with the URL itself and not the code, but I cannot for the life of me come across a service to upload and stream a .WAV file so that the program can capture the audio like in the original code with the :

http://pscode.org/media/leftright.wav

I am not sure if the code would have to be tweaked a bit for the to support mediafire's player or if there is another service for upload that support this.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I opened your mediafire URL and got redirected to a captcha. Maybe that's the issue.

Comment: @Jigar Joshi, thank for the edit.

Comment: @ZoveGames do you know of other service to upload that lets you stream? Most of the ones I found give you a url like : Vocaroo.com/857hsgf? or thinks like that.

Comment: Try Google Drive and use the Drive Java API to load the file. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2

Comment: It didn't work because it had issues with the .wav.  Damn

Comment: I looked at your .wav and didn't have any issues. It seems to be a supported Java format: 44100 fps, 16-bit encoding, stereo. The only thing not mentioned in the properties was whether it was little-endian or big-endian. Will investigate further.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner Thanks a lot! I don't know about the endian property but to my rather limited knowledge it should work, I fear it has to do with the hosting service rather than the file.